# Why pandas dataframe describe().min method returns standard deviation instead?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to subtract the minimum value of each column from all values in that column in a pandas dataframe. But when using `df.describe().min[columnName]` to get the minimum value of that column, it returns the minimum values correctly except for the last column, it seems to return the standard deviation instead.  Here is an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# create dictionary and dataframe
dfDict = {'A': [1,2,3,4], 'B':[2,4,6,8],'C': [3,5,7,9]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dfDict)
```

```
print(df)
```

output:

```
   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
1  2  4  5
2  3  6  7
3  4  8  9
```

When I `print(df.describe())` this value seems to be ok, Output:

```
              A         B         C
count  4.000000  4.000000  4.000000
mean   2.500000  5.000000  6.000000
std    1.290994  2.581989  2.581989
min    1.000000  2.000000  3.000000
25%    1.750000  3.500000  4.500000
50%    2.500000  5.000000  6.000000
75%    3.250000  6.500000  7.500000
max    4.000000  8.000000  9.000000
```

But when I `print(df.describe().min())`, the value for C is not the minimum value but rather the standard deviation, I get this output:

```
A    1.000000
B    2.000000
C    2.581989
dtype: float64
```

Ultimately, I want to subtract the minimum value of each column from all the values in that column. I tried doing so as follows:

```
iterColNames = df.columns.tolist()
for colName in iterColNames:
    df[colName] = df[colName]-df.describe().min()[colName]
```

This leads to good values for the first two columns but not the last one.
If I `print(df)` now, it gives me this output:

```
     A    B         C
0  0.0  0.0  0.418011
1  1.0  2.0  2.418011
2  2.0  4.0  4.418011
3  3.0  6.0  6.418011
```

Where it should give me the following output instead:

```
     A    B    C
0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1  1.0  2.0  2.0
2  2.0  4.0  4.0
3  3.0  6.0  6.0
```

This seems rather simple but I am not sure what is the reason from this problem.
Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
print(df.describe().min())
```

will compute minimum values for the (pseudo-)dataframe that `df.describe()` returns, which will likely not make much sense.

Instead, simply

```
>>> df.min()
A    1
B    2
C    3
```

will return column-wise minimums.

Answer (score 2):

This will give you the result you are looking for:

```
df - df.min()

    A   B   C
0   0   0   0
1   1   2   2
2   2   4   4
3   3   6   6
```

[df.min()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.min.html) calculates the minimum for each column. And when you subtract this minimum from your df, pandas will subtract it from every value in the column. No need to use for loops. Try to avoid for loops when using pandas. Pandas uses vectorized operations, they are a lot faster in general.

Answer (score 1):

As a supplement to the other answers, which are generally better solutions to your question:

If you want to select a specific row by index in a dataframe like `df.describe()` you can use [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

```
df.describe().loc['min']
```

Out:

```
A    1.0
B    2.0
C    3.0
Name: min, dtype: float64
```

To get your desired output

```
df - df.describe().loc['min']
```

Out:

```
     A    B    C
0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1  1.0  2.0  2.0
2  2.0  4.0  4.0
3  3.0  6.0  6.0
```